# Javascript: prototypal inherence and super constructor

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

how can i call super constructor from the inheriting object? for example, i have a simple animal 'class':

```
function Animal(legs) {
  this.legs = legs;
}
```

i want to create a 'Chimera' class that inherits from Animal but sets the number of legs to a random number (providing the maximum number of legs in the constructor. so far i have this:

```
function Chimera(maxLegs) {
    // generate [randLegs] maxed to maxLegs
    // call Animal's constructor with [randLegs]
}
Chimera.prototype = new Animal;
Chimera.prototype.constructor = Chimera;
```

how to call Animal's constructor? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is similar to [constructor chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply#Using_apply_to_chain_constructors):

```
function Chimera(maxLegs) {
    // generate [randLegs] maxed to maxLegs
    // call Animal's constructor with [randLegs]
    Animal.call(this, randLegs);
}
```

Or you may consider [Parasitic Inheritance](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html)

```
function Chimera(maxLegs) {

    // generate [randLegs] maxed to maxLegs
    // ...

    // call Animal's constructor with [randLegs]
    var that = new Animal(randLegs);

    // add new properties and methods to that
    // ...

    return that;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method every function has:

```
function Chimera(maxLegs) {
   var randLegs = ...;
   Animal.call(this, randLegs);
}
```

Comment: i get an error in the "Chimera.prototype = new Animal;" part because i think it calls Animal() without the parameters while instantiated

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to do this:

```
new Animal();
```

Comment: FYI, the reason you were downvoted is because, while this will call the Animal constructor, it will not call the animal constructor *on the current object*.

Comment: Down voting seems a tad extreme.  You could have just corrected me, rather than punishing me.